# Set custom value when item moved to folder in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, user-defined-fields

I'm looking to set a Date on a field anytime an email is moved into a specific folder. 
the field is custom called "Completed Date". 
Could I get a little help on VBA code to set a custom field (date) when an item is moved into a folder (folder name is "Completed").

I'm ultimately looking to report on the time an item (custom form email) was received to the time it was completed (as per the action of moving the email to a completed folder.

Very rudimentary ticketing system, I'm very aware :) .

thanks,

A

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemAdd http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62 where you reference the "Completed" folder.

Combine it with code like this http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?5738-Need-to-Add-a-Userdefined-Property-to-Mail-Items

**SAMPLE CODE**

Change it so you do **not** update all items in the folder just the one item that triggered ItemAdd.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub AddAUserDefinedProperty() 

Dim olApplication   As Outlook.Application 
Dim olNameSpace     As Outlook.NameSpace 
Dim olFolder        As Outlook.MAPIFolder 
Dim olItem          As Object 
Dim strDomain       As String 
Dim olProperty      As Outlook.UserProperty 

Set olApplication = New Outlook.Application 
Set olNameSpace = olApplication.GetNamespace("Mapi") 
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk) 

For Each olItem In olFolder.Items 

    strDomain = Mid(olItem.SenderEmailAddress, _ 
    InStr(1, olItem.SenderEmailAddress, "@") + 1) 

    Set olProperty = olItem.UserProperties.Add("Domain", olText) 

    olProperty.Value = strDomain 

    Debug.Print olItem.SenderEmailAddress, olProperty.Value 

    olItem.Save 

Next olItem 

Set olApplication = Nothing 
Set olNameSpace = Nothing 
Set olFolder = Nothing 
Set olProperty = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Even more reference material here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/427913/Using-User-Defined-Fields-in-Outlook