# Original "start date" of postponed appointment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Hopefully someone could help :)

I use VBA code that runs through Microsoft Outlook Appointments, and for each appointment - prints a few details - to an Excel table.

If I set the start date of an appointment on `01-April-2019`, and then postpone that appointment to `12-April-2019`, and then postpone that appointment to `15-April-2019` - I have 3 "Appointment Item" objects in my folder.

I would like to print for each appointment in the folder - the "Start Date" that was set ***originally***.

For example: Print for the first appointment - the first original start date (`01-April-2019`), for the first postponed appointment - the first postponed start date (`12-April-2019`), and for the second postponed appointment - the second postponed start date (`15-April-2019`).

However, when I run my code - the ***last*** "Start Date" is printed (`15-April-2019, 15-April-2019, 15-April-2019`), instead of the original (`01-April-2019, 12-April-2019, 15-April-2019`) .

I read a lot about different types of "date" objects, but couldn't find the correct one.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

'Early Binding: Tools > References > Microsoft Outlook xx.0 Object Library > OK

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNS As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oG As Outlook.Folder  'Method for IMAP, as used by Gmail.
Dim oM As Outlook.MeetingItem
Dim oAA As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim oI As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
Dim sMsg$, sAdd$
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNS = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("CCB Meetings")


 Dim icon As String

  Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set oG = OutlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("CCB Meetings")

  For i = 1 To oG.Items.Count
   If TypeName(oG.Items(i)) = "MeetingItem" Then j = j + 1
  Next i
  If j = 0 Then Exit Sub

' Create titles
        Range("A1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "SenderName"
        Range("B1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Subject"
        Range("C1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "CreationTime (Scheduled time of the first appointment)"
        Range("D1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "ReceivedTime (Scheduled time of the current appointment)"
        Range("E1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Start (start time of the last scheduled appointment)"
        Range("F1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "StartTime (doesnt work yet)"
        Range("G1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Location"
        Range("H1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "RequiredAttendees"
        Range("I1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "OptionalAttendees"
        Range("J1").Offset(0, 0).Value = "ResponseStatus"


  On Error Resume Next
  j = 0
  For i = 1 To oG.Items.Count
      Set oM = oG.Items(i)
     With oG.Items(i).GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
       j = j + 1
       Range("A1").Offset(j, 0).Value = oM.SenderName
       Range("B1").Offset(j, 0).Value = oM.Subject
       Range("C1").Offset(j, 0).Value = .CreationTime
       Range("D1").Offset(j, 0).Value = oM.ReceivedTime
       Range("E1").Offset(j, 0).Value = .Start
       Range("F1").Offset(j, 0).Value = oAA.GetRecurrencePattern '??????????????????
       Range("G1").Offset(j, 0).Value = .Location
       Range("H1").Offset(j, 0).Value = .RequiredAttendees
       Range("I1").Offset(j, 0).Value = .OptionalAttendees
       Range("J1").Offset(j, 0).Value = .ResponseStatus

     End With
  Next i
  On Error GoTo 0


Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNS = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have never been interested in the change history of an appointment.  My interest has been in single appointments, recurring appointments and changed single occurrences of a recurring appointment.  There is a link from a changed single occurrence of a recurring appointment to the original date.  However, I have never noticed the changing of a single appointment creating a new `AppointmentItem`.  Neither have I noticed any change history within a single appointment.  Have you reason to believe that a change history is recorded?

Comment: Niton suggests using a custom property to record the change history.  Given that you want the history in an Excel workbook, I would output the change to the workbook.  Either way, I would investigate the `ChangeProperty` event to see if it offered a convenient method of recording the change.

Comment: Thank you! I've read a little about the "ChangeProperty", and so far couldn't figure out how to use it exactly in order to solve my issue. Hopefully you could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UserProperties field manually or Add a UserProperties field with VBA code.

[UserProperties object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties)

[UserProperties.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add)

[OlUserPropertyType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oluserpropertytype)

Once you have the field you can enter data manually or with VBA.

With VBA consider ItemAdd. [Set custom value when item moved to folder in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532189/set-custom-value-when-item-moved-to-folder-in-outlook)

Comment: Thanks! :)
I read a little about it, but I don't understand how exactly I can get the dates history property out of it... Hopefully could you guide me?

Comment: When there is no built-in property you can create your own. You create the history yourself when you put the data into the field at the same time the item is created.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed Niton's latest comment.  I think it is an interesting idea.  I suspect you still need my investigative macro and you will still need events to create the custom property so this answer should still be useful.

I would need to invest more time than I have available at the moment to address your requirement.  This answer includes what I have to hand in the hope that it will help you.

Your code suggests you do not understand recurring entries, you are not familiar with the different types of calendar items and you have misinterpreted some of the properties.  If there is any detailed documentation on calendar items available via the internet, I have failed to find it.  There is basic documentation (referenced below): this object has these properties; this property is a long/string/enumeration; one sentence definitions and so on.  But none of this basic documentation helped me understand how, for example, exceptions related to master entries.

The code below is an Excel based investigation I conducted some months ago.  I have not had the time to move to the next stage but I believe it will give you a start.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DiagCal()

  ' Outputs major properties of all calendar items within the default
  ' calendar for a specified date range.  The objective is to better
  ' understand calendar items and how they link.

  ' Requires reference to Microsoft Outlook nn.n Library
  ' where "nn.n" identifies the version of Office you are using.

  ' 27Dec18  First version coded
  ' 30Dec18  This version coded
  ' 18Apr19  Reviewed comments and made some improvements.

  ' * Together these constants identify the start and length of the report period.
  ' * The report period starts DateReportStartOffset days before today.
  ' * DateReportLenType and DateReportLen are used as parameters for function DateAdd
  '   which is used to calculate the report period end date for the start date.  See
  '   function DateAdd for permitted values for these constants.
  ' * These constants provided a convenient way of specify the start and end date
  '   of the report period when this macro was written. Something simpler would
  '   probably be better now.
  Const DateReportLen As Long = 1
  Const DateReportLenType As String = "yyyy"
  Const DateReportStartOffset As Long = -363

  Dim AppointToReport As New Collection
  Dim AppOutlook As New Outlook.Application
  Dim CalEnt As Object
  Dim CalEntClass As Long
  Dim DateReportEnd As Date
  Dim DateReportStart As Date
  Dim FileBody As String
  Dim FldrCal As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxAir As Long
  Dim InxFC As Long
  Dim PathDesktop As String

  PathDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

  ' Identify date range to be reported on
  DateReportStart = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + DateReportStartOffset)
  DateReportEnd = DateAdd(DateReportLenType, DateReportLen, DateReportStart)

  ' This assumes the calendar of interest is the default calendar.
  ' Change as necessary
  Set FldrCal = AppOutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

  ' This loop reviews the entire calendar and identifies Calendar Items
  ' that fall entirely or partially within the report period. All such
  ' Calendar Items are recorded in collection AppointToReport.
  For InxFC = 1 To FldrCal.Items.Count

    Set CalEnt = FldrCal.Items(InxFC)

    ' Occasionally I get syncronisation errors.  This code avoids them.
    CalEntClass = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    CalEntClass = CalEnt.Class
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' I have never found anything but appointments in
    ' Calendar but test just in case
    If CalEntClass = olAppointment Then
      Call DiagCalRecordEntry(CalEnt, DateReportStart, DateReportEnd, AppointToReport)
    End If

  Next InxFC

  FileBody = "Calendar entries within or partially within " & _
             Format(DateReportStart, "d mmm yy") & _
             " to " & Format(DateReportEnd, "d mmm yy") & vbLf & _
             "Total calendar entries: " & FldrCal.Items.Count & vbLf & _
             "Calendar entries within or partially within report period: " & _
             AppointToReport.Count

  ' This loop outputs the major properties of every Calendar Items recorded
  ' in collection AppointToReport.
  For InxAir = 1 To AppointToReport.Count
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & String(70, "=")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & AppointToReport(InxAir)(1)
  Next

  Call PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(PathDesktop & "\Calendar.txt", FileBody)

End Sub
Sub DiagCalRecordEntry(ByRef CalEnt As Object, _
                       ByVal DateReportStart As Date, _
                       ByVal DateReportEnd As Date, _
                       ByRef AppointToReport As Collection, _
                       Optional ByVal OriginalDate As Date)

  ' If calendar entry is within or partially within report range, add
  ' its details to AppointToReport

  Dim AllDayEvent As Boolean
  Dim AppointDtls As String
  Dim AppointId As String
  Dim AppointIdMaster As String
  Dim BusyStatus As String
  Dim DateRecurrEnd As Date
  Dim DateRecurrStart As Date
  Dim DateAppointEnd As Date
  Dim DateAppointStart As Date
  Dim DayOfMonth As Long
  Dim DayOfWeekMask As String
  Dim DayOfWeekMaskCode As Long
  Dim DurationEntry As Long
  Dim DurationRecurr As Long
  Dim InxE As Long
  Dim Instance As Long
  Dim Interval As Long
  Dim Location As String
  Dim MonthOfYear As Long
  Dim NoEndDate As Boolean
  Dim NumOccurrences As Long
  Dim RecurrenceState As String
  Dim RecurrenceType As String
  Dim RecurrPattern As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
  Dim Subject As String
  Dim TimeStart As Date
  Dim TimeEnd As Date

  'Debug.Assert False

  ' Get values from calendar entry which identify if entry is within
  ' report range
  With CalEnt
    DateAppointStart = .Start
    DateAppointEnd = .End
    Select Case .RecurrenceState
      Case olApptNotRecurring
        'Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Non-recurring calendar entry"
      Case olApptMaster
        'Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Master calendar entry"
      Case olApptException
        'Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Exception to Master calendar entry"
      Case olApptOccurrence
        Debug.Assert False
        ' I believe this state can only exist if GetOccurrence() is used
        ' to get a single occurrence of a Master entery. I do not believe
        ' it can appear as a calendar entry
        RecurrenceState = "Occurrence"
      Case Else
        Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Unrecognised (" & .RecurrenceState & ")"
    End Select
  End With

  If RecurrenceState = "Master calendar entry" Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    Set RecurrPattern = CalEnt.GetRecurrencePattern()
    With RecurrPattern
      DateRecurrStart = .PatternStartDate
      DateRecurrEnd = .PatternEndDate
    End With
    If DateRecurrStart <= DateReportEnd And _
       DateRecurrEnd >= DateReportStart Then
      ' Some or all occurences of this Master entry are within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
    Else
      ' No occurences of this Master entry are within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Else
    ' Non recurring or exception appointment
    If DateAppointStart <= DateReportEnd And _
       DateAppointEnd >= DateReportStart Then
      ' Entry is within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
    Else
      ' Non recurring entry is not within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

  ' Calendar entry is within or partially within report period

  ' Get remaining properties from entry
  'Debug.Assert False
  With CalEnt
    AllDayEvent = .AllDayEvent
    AppointId = .GlobalAppointmentID
    Select Case .BusyStatus
      Case olBusy
        'Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Busy"
      Case olFree
        'Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Free"
      Case olOutOfOffice
       'Debug.Assert False
       BusyStatus = "Out of Office"
      Case olTentative
        Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Tentative appointment"
      Case olWorkingElsewhere
        'Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Working elsewhere"
      Case Else
        Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Not recognised (" & .BusyStatus & ")"
    End Select
    Location = .Location
    Subject = .Subject
  End With

  If RecurrenceState = "Exception to Master calendar entry" Then
    RecurrenceState = RecurrenceState & vbLf & _
                      "Master's Id: " & CalEnt.Parent.GlobalAppointmentID & vbLf & _
                      "Original Date: " & OriginalDate
  End If

  AppointDtls = RecurrenceState & vbLf & _
                "AllDayEvent: " & AllDayEvent & vbLf & _
                "AppointId: " & AppointId & vbLf & _
                "BusyStatus: " & BusyStatus & vbLf & _
                "DateAppointStart: " & DateAppointStart & vbLf & _
                "DateAppointEnd: " & DateAppointEnd & vbLf & _
                "DurationEntry: " & DurationEntry & vbLf & _
                "Location: " & Location & vbLf & _
                "Subject: " & Subject

  If RecurrenceState <> "Master calendar entry" Then
    ' AppointDtls complete for this appointment
    Call StoreSingleAppoint(Format(DateAppointStart, "yyyymmddhhmm"), _
                            AppointDtls, AppointToReport)
  Else
    'Debug.Assert False
    With RecurrPattern
      ' Not all parameters have a meaningful value for all RecurrenceTypes
      ' but the value always appears to be of the correct data type.
      DateRecurrStart = .PatternStartDate
      DateRecurrEnd = .PatternEndDate
      DayOfMonth = .DayOfMonth
      DayOfWeekMaskCode = .DayOfWeekMask
      DayOfWeekMask = ""
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olSaturday Then
        Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Saturday"
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olSaturday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olFriday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Friday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olFriday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olThursday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Thursday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olThursday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olWednesday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Wednesday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olWednesday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olTuesday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Tuesday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olTuesday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olMonday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Monday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olMonday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olSunday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Sunday" & DayOfWeekMask
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMask = "" Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "None"
      Else
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = Mid$(DayOfWeekMask, 2) ' Remove leading +
      End If
      DurationRecurr = .Duration
      Instance = .Instance
      Interval = .Interval
      MonthOfYear = .MonthOfYear
      NoEndDate = .NoEndDate
      NumOccurrences = .Occurrences
      Select Case .RecurrenceType
        Case olRecursDaily
          'Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Daily"
        Case olRecursMonthly
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Monthly"
        Case olRecursMonthNth
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "MonthNth"
        Case olRecursWeekly
          'Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Weekly"
        Case olRecursYearly
          'Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Yearly"
        Case olRecursYearNth
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "YearNth"
        Case Else
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Unrecognised Value (" & RecurrenceType & ")"
      End Select
      TimeStart = .StartTime
      TimeEnd = .EndTime
    End With

    AppointDtls = AppointDtls & vbLf & "DateRecurrStart: " & DateRecurrStart _
                              & vbLf & "DateRecurrEnd: " & DateRecurrEnd _
                              & vbLf & "DayOfMonth: " & DayOfMonth _
                              & vbLf & "DayOfWeekMask: " & DayOfWeekMask _
                              & vbLf & "DurationRecurr: " & DurationRecurr _
                              & vbLf & "Instance: " & Instance _
                              & vbLf & "Interval: " & Interval _
                              & vbLf & "MonthOfYear: " & MonthOfYear _
                              & vbLf & "NoEndDate: " & NoEndDate _
                              & vbLf & "NumOccurrences: " & NumOccurrences _
                              & vbLf & "RecurrenceType: " & RecurrenceType _
                              & vbLf & "TimeStart: " & TimeStart & " (" & CDbl(TimeStart) & ")" _
                              & vbLf & "TimeEnd: " & TimeEnd & " (" & CDbl(TimeEnd) & ")"

    For InxE = 1 To RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Count
      AppointDtls = AppointDtls & vbLf & "Exception " & InxE & " for occurrence on " & _
                                   RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Item(InxE).OriginalDate
    Next

    Call StoreSingleAppoint(Format(DateRecurrStart, "yyyymmddhhmm"), _
                            AppointDtls, AppointToReport)

    For InxE = 1 To RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Count
      Call DiagCalRecordEntry(RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Item(InxE).AppointmentItem, _
                              DateReportStart, DateReportEnd, AppointToReport, _
                              RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Item(InxE).OriginalDate)
    Next

  End If ' RecurrenceState <> "Master calendar entry"

End Sub
Public Sub PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(ByVal PathFileName As String, ByVal FileBody As String)

  ' Outputs FileBody as a text file named PathFileName using
  ' UTF-8 encoding without leading BOM

  ' Needs reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library"
  ' Addition to original code says version 2.5. Tested with version 6.1.

  '  1Nov16  Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '          but replaced literals with parameters.
  ' 15Aug17  Discovered routine was adding an LF to the end of the file.
  '          Added code to discard that LF.
  ' 11Oct17  Posted to StackOverflow
  '  9Aug18  Comment from rellampec suggested removal of adWriteLine from
  '          WriteTest statement would avoid adding LF.
  ' 30Sep18  Amended routine to remove adWriteLine from WriteTest statement
  '          and code to remove LF from file. Successfully tested new version.

  ' References: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '             https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp

  Dim BinaryStream As Object
  Dim UTFStream As Object

  Set UTFStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")

  UTFStream.Type = adTypeText
  UTFStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  UTFStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  UTFStream.Open
  UTFStream.WriteText FileBody

  UTFStream.Position = 3 'skip BOM

  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
  BinaryStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  BinaryStream.Open

  UTFStream.CopyTo BinaryStream

  UTFStream.Flush
  UTFStream.Close
  Set UTFStream = Nothing

  BinaryStream.SaveToFile PathFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
  BinaryStream.Flush
  BinaryStream.Close
  Set BinaryStream = Nothing

End Sub
Sub StoreSingleAppoint(ByVal SeqKey As String, _
                       ByVal AppointDtls As String, _
                       ByRef AppointToReport As Collection)

  ' Entries in AppointToReport are of the form:
  '    VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls)
  ' Add new entry to AppointToReport so entries are in ascending order by SeqKey

  Dim InxAtr As Long

  If AppointToReport.Count = 0 Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    ' first appointment
    AppointToReport.Add VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls)
    Else
    For InxAtr = AppointToReport.Count To 1 Step -1
      If SeqKey >= AppointToReport(InxAtr)(0) Then
        ' New appointment belongs after this existing entry
        'Debug.Assert False
        AppointToReport.Add VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls), , , InxAtr
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next
    ' If get here, new appointment belongs before all existing appointments
    'Debug.Assert False
    AppointToReport.Add VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls), , 1
  End If

End Sub
```

Create a macro-enabled workbook and copy the above code to a module.

Near the top of the code you will find:

```
  ' Identify date range to be reported on
  DateReportStart = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + DateReportStartOffset)
  DateReportEnd = DateAdd(DateReportLenType, DateReportLen, DateReportStart)
```

I suggest replacing these statements with something simple like:

```
  DateReportStart = #4/15/2019#
  DateReportEnd = #4/18/2019#
```

Warning: VBA date literals use middle-endian format which confuses everyone except civilian Americans.

Macro `DiagCal()` creates a desktop file named “Calendar.txt” containing details of every calendar item that is entirely or partially within the report period.  When I tested it, I created every sort of calendar entry: single appointments; entries recurring by day, week, month, year; weekly patterns; multi-day, all-day and part-day events; exceptions to instances of recurring entries and so on.

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.AppointmentItem

On the left is an index with entries for the events, methods and properties of an appointment item.  Expand the properties and methods and look for information that did not interest me but might interest you.  Look through my code and workout how to add that information.  If you cannot see how to add information, report the information you want in a comment and I will add it for you.

Expand the events and study what is available.  I have never used appointment item events.  I have found events easy enough to use with mail items so I assume appointment items will be similar.  It is not immediate clear to me which would be the best events to use.  I think you need to know when a new item is added and when an item is changed.  I would try some of these events and write code to output a few properties to the Immediate Windows to better understand when these events are triggered and what data is available.

I believe you will have to initialise your workbook with code something like my macro which extracts the interesting properties of existing appointment items.  You then need events to output the interesting properties of new or changed events.

I would not use events to update the workbook.  (1) If you update the workbook in real time there will probably be a noticeable delay while the event is processed.  (2) The update code is likely to be complex and unlikely to be correct on first attempt.  If you update the workbook in real time, you will have to cause the events to be triggered again and again until you get the code right.

I would get each event to output a small text file, containing the interesting properties, to a suitable disc folder.  Outputting a text file will be take little time and should not be noticeable to the user.  These text files can be used again and again to update the workbook until you get the code right.

I hope the above gives you some ideas.